# IndexError: list index out of range in prediction of images

Tags: pytorch, classification, prediction, image-classification

I am doing predictions on images where I write all classes' names and in the test folder, I have 20 images. Please give me some hint as, why I am getting error? How we can check the indices of the model?

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import sys, random
import torch
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

# Paths for image directory and model
IMDIR = './test'
MODEL = 'checkpoint/resnet18/Monday_31_May_2021_21h_25m_05s/resnet18-1000-regular.pth'

# Load the model for testing
model = models.resnet18()

model.named_children()

torch.save(model.state_dict, MODEL)
model.eval()

# Class labels for prediction
class_names = ['BC', 'BK', 'CC', 'CL', 'CM', 'DF', 'DG', 'DS', 'HL', 'IF', 'JD', 'JS', 'LD', 'LP', 'LS', 'PO', 'RI',
               'SD', 'SG', 'TO']


# Retreive 9 random images from directory
files = Path(IMDIR).resolve().glob('*.*')
print(files)

images = random.sample(list(files), 1)
print(images)
# Configure plots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
rows, cols = 3, 3

# Preprocessing transformations
preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((256, 256)),
    # transforms.CenterCrop(size=224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(0.5306, 0.1348)
])

# Enable gpu mode, if cuda available
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Perform prediction and plot results
with torch.no_grad():
    for num, img in enumerate(images):
        img = Image.open(img).convert('RGB')
        inputs = preprocess(img).unsqueeze(0).cpu()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        print(preds)
        label = class_names[preds]
        plt.subplot(rows, cols, num + 1)
        plt.title("Pred: " + label)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(img)
'''
Sample run: python test.py test
'''
```

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/khawar/HDD_Khawar/CVPR/pytorch-cifar100/test_box.py", line 57, in <module>
    label = class_names[preds]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What's the output of print(preds)? It's obvious that the max function is returning a higher value than the length of class_names.

Comment: tensor([86]). I need the output like class label name

Comment: You are loading imagenet-trained resnet18 (not pretrained, too, it seems, is this an error?), which has 1000 classes. You're trying to sort these into your 10-20 class names.

Comment: This resnet18 is my model

Comment: You're not loading the model at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stems from the fact that you don't do any modification to the linear layers of your resnet model.

I suggest adding this code:

```
# What you have
model = models.resnet18()

# What you need
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(model.fc.in_features, len(class_names)))
```

This changes the last linear layers to outputting the correct amount of nodes

Sarthak